# How can I set default date url parameter for a radio schedule in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a route setup to a radio show schedule, the parameter I pass to the `ScheduleComponent` is the date. However I'm having problems trying to set a default value for the route.

After a lot of failures I settled for always setting the date on the link. But now I need to highlight the `.active` route so need to work out how to set the default value for schedule.

Can someone please help to point me in the right direction.

Current route:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: 'schedule/:date',
        component: ScheduleComponent,
    }
]
```

I'm looking at doing something like this, but can't get schedule to go to the right place with out a given date. I'm not sure this is the right way to go about it either:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: 'schedule',
        component: ScheduleComponent,
        redirectTo: 'schedule/yyyy-MM-dd', // Replacing yyyy-MM-dd with todays date.
        children: [
            { path: ':date', component: ScheduleComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
        ]
    }
]
```

Main navigation contructor, this is where I want to just use `/schedule`:

```
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe, private colorService: ColorService) {
    this.navs = [
      {url: '/schedule/' + this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd"), content: "Schedule"},
      // ... other routes
    ];
```

Example Link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/schedule', day | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd']"
     routerLinkActive="active"
     class="schedule-nav-button">
     {{day | date:"EEE"}}
</a>
```

Schedule Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map"
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap"
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import {ColorService} from "../../services/color.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-schedule',
    templateUrl: '../views/schedule.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../css/schedule.component.css']
})
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
    schedule$ = new BehaviorSubject([{
        "start_time": new Date(),
        "end_time": new Date(),
        "radio_show": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Loading...",
            "description": "",
            "small_thumb": "",
            "presenters": [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "Loading.."
                }
            ]
        }
    },]);
    date: Date;

    constructor(@Inject('api') private api, private colorService: ColorService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: Http) {
        this.date = new Date();
        route.params
            .map((p: any) => p.date)
            .switchMap(date => http.get(api + '/schedules/' + date)
                .map(res => res.json())
            ).subscribe(this.schedule$);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.colorService.change("blue");
    }

}
```

**Update**

This was my solution. As Thomas Schoutsens suggested I set my routes to point to the same component.

```
const routes = [
    { path: 'schedule/:date', component: ScheduleComponent },
    { path: 'schedule', component: ScheduleComponent }
]
```

Then I added an or statement to add the default date if none was provided `(date || this.datePipe.transform(this.date, "yyyy-MM-dd"))`.

```
constructor(@Inject('api') private api, private datePipe: DatePipe, private colorService: ColorService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: Http) {
        this.date = new Date();
        route.params
            .map((p: any) => p.date)
            .switchMap(date => http.get(api + '/schedules/' + (date || this.datePipe.transform(this.date, "yyyy-MM-dd")))
                .map(res => res.json())
            ).subscribe(this.schedule$);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but don't you basically want the date parameter to be optional? If parameter is provided, use that date (`/schedule/2017-06-17`). If not provided (`/schedule`), just set date in the component itself? If that's the case you can simply have 2 routes using the same component. (`/schedule/:date` and `/schedule`). Correct me if I'm wrong in understanding and I will try to provide a real answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using a default parameter with today's date, make the parameter optional and if needed set the default date in the component.

To make the parameter optional, create 2 routes using the same component:

```
const routes = [
    { path: 'schedule/:date', component: ScheduleComponent },
    { path: 'schedule', component: ScheduleComponent }
]
```

Then in your component:

```
route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.date = params['date'];
    if(!date)
        this.date = new Date();
});
```